# Imperative vs. Declarative (can a third grader or his parents tell the difference?)

Tags: imperatives

My 3rd grade son was supposed to write a series of sentences, and write whether they were "imperative" or "declarative" (or "interogative" or "exclamatory", but those aren't relevant for this question).

The sentence he wrote was "You must join with the giants."

My thoughts were that, despite the fact that this sounds like an order, that this sentence was declarative.  My wife insisted it was imperative.  My third grader was confused as all get out by our contradictory opinions.

Her thoughts were that an imperative tells someone to do something...that's what this sentence is.  QED.

I was thinking that although it sounds like an imperative type order, by changing the words slightly, say changing the "you" into "I", or "must" into "should" or "might" it becomes more obvious (to me) that the sentence is making a declaration of state, rather than an order for immediate action.

I *think* I'm right, but would like to be sure (or be told why I am wrong).  I'd also like the correct terminology pointed out to me where I've doubtless messed it up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it is not in the imperative.  An imperative verb almost never has a subject. These are imperative sentences:

- Go to the store.
- Michael, go to the store.
- You give me that right now.

These are all declarative sentences:

- You are going to the store.
- You will go to the store.
- You might go to the store.
- You should go to the store.
- You have to go to the store.
- You ought to go to the store.
- You *shall* go to the store.
- You must go to the store.

How you want to classify this one, however, may vary:

- Let's go to the store.

Comment: That's correct, by the steampunk Latinate rules. In Latin, all the verbs were marked (including special forms for "let's"), and you could tell the imperatives from the declaratives instantly, like color-coding. In English, the distinction is not as useful, because real imperatives are thin on the ground; they're almost always mollified or metaphored, because using a bald imperative is tantamount to pulling rank. There are lots of ways to do this; they teach courses about it, in fact, under the name of "Management".

Comment: @JohnLawler He wasn’t asking about some hypothetical  morphological indicator on a one-word verb. He was asking about the entire sentence. In American grade schools, including the 3rd grader mentioned in the OP’s question, our children are taught that all English sentences can be classified as one of exactly four possible forms: ***declarative, interrogative, imperative,*** and ***exclamatory***.  We aren’t talking about morphology here, John: please try to think of the children.

Comment: It's not me forcing children to memorize BS in the schools. I'm not responsible for the faults of their teachers. I'm just responsible for not lying to them. If they find out too early that they're being lied to, too bad.

Comment: @JohnLawler How is it a lie to ask children to distinguish between “declarative” sentences and “interrogative” sentences? It’s just a model to help kids figure out what sort of terminal punctuation to place at the end of a sentence? Don’t you think it helps.

Comment: It's not a model of the English language. And anybody who says it is is lying. Call it something else like religion or music and you can say anything you want. But if you're sposta be teaching kids about their language, don't waste their time, and don't waste their education telling them stuff they'll have to unlearn later on. Education is **important**.

Comment: @JohnLawler Perhaps you have a better idea about teaching a ten-year-old what mark of punctuation to end a sentence with? If so, I wonder why it hasn’t been tried.

Comment: Simple. If you mean it to be a question, and you expect an answer, use a question mark. Anything else, use a period.

Comment: @JohnLawler (facepalm) Yup, you’re right.

Comment: @JohnLawler I would absolutely agree that education is important.  But while it bothers me on a purist level to simplify things to the point where they're not completely true, I also believe that it is absolutely critical to do so for kids to learn some things.  The classic example is the cylinder problem...it is well established that kids before a certain developmental milestone will *always* think the taller cylinder holds more than a short, but much fatter cylinder, no matter what is done to prove otherwise, because their brains are simply not ready for it...

Comment: @JohnLawler (...continued)  Likewise, one could try to teach high school students introductory physics by going into the theory of relativity, instead of classical physics because Newtonian physics isn't completely true.  But the great majority of them wouldn't get it, because they're not ready for it yet.  Kids understand that things are simplified for them, and accept that, as they grow older, things become more complicated than they first realized.  As long as the the early methods are not too dogmatic and labeled as final truths etched in stone, I think they can be useful learning tools.

Comment: That might be true if there were any grammar education after grade school. But there isn't. Hands up, everybody who took maths in college -- now hands up, everybody who took English grammar in college. Wow, what a difference. High school, anyone? Same pattern.

Comment: I sympathize with your feelings, but overloading someone early because you feel they won't likely have the opportunity to learn it later seems counterproductive.  That just seems like a path to ensuring that they won't learn as much now, simply for the sake of sticking dogmatically to a "truth" at all costs.  That said, I have no evidence one way or the other.  Just an (vaguely) educated guess.

Answer (score 8):

"Join with the giants" is in the imperative mood.  (It's a direct command. It has an implied subject of "you," but the subject itself is not stated.)

"You must join with the giants" in the declarative mood because it expresses a fact not a command.  For example, you could say "You must join with the giants if you're going to fight the dragons."

**The confusion arises from the usage of the [deontic modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality) "must."**  Because  a deontic modal implies the way the world ought to be rather than the way the world is, it is a statement of belief about what needs to be changed.  It is not, however, an explicit command to change anything.

For your third grader, it's probably fine just to say that it's an imperative because it's saying you have to do something.  Let him learn the subtler linguistic distinction when he's older.  For now, meaning matters more than syntax.

Comment: I like the last paragraph.  This is exactly what I was worrying about...whether I was going to potentially sacrifice his overall understanding for the sake of a pedantic point.  "Good enough for now" is excellent way to look at this.

Comment: @beska: except the last paragraph doesn't help answer a test question. In schools, as opposed to real life, there is only one answer. But also, trying to get one answer helps the student develop reasoning.

Comment: @Mitch True.  In that case, we just need to talk to the teacher to find out what the rules they're looking for are.

Answer (score 2):

This is all about terminology. As the others have said, on a syntactic level, it is in the **indicative mood** (not imperative); on a semantic/illocutionary level, it is a **directive** (not an assertive, declarative, interrogative, or expressive). The term *imperative* is usually restricted to the syntactic mood, so you should probably be looking at that; then your son's sentence is indicative.

The other terms, however, make one think of illocutionary functions. The opposition *imperative v. declarative* makes it seem as though his teacher were confusing semantics with syntax or were just generally imprecise. In that case, it's anybody's guess what she meant. See [Speech Acts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illocutionary_act) and [Moods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood).

Comment: Why, a third grader could understand this stuff. Somebody run outside and bring me a third grader.

Comment: Children here are taught that all English sentences are one of four types: declarative, interrogative, imperative, and exclamatory. That’s really all there is to it. We do not need to bring Latinate verb morphology into it — and in fact, must not. That isn’t the point. Interrogative sentences end with a question mark, exclamatory ones with an exclamation point, and imperative ones (usually) have an implicit 2nd person subject (although sometimes with a vocative-of-attention). All the rest are declarative. That’s how they do things with our kids, and that is all the querent needs to know.

Comment: @tchrist: This is unrelated to Latin.

Comment: @tchrist: 'Her thoughts were that an imperative tells someone to do something...that's what this sentence is.' Clever girl. She's using advanced analytical techniques - at her age. She sees that meaning is the real basis of language, and that syntax is merely a framework to facilitate accurate communication. And I feel she's being let down by an over-emphasis on (one? two? variants of) esoteric terminology and (one) prescriptive classification system.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the following at http://voices.yahoo.com/four-kinds-sentences-declarative-interrogative-484238.html?cat=4 :

> Four Kinds of Sentences: Declarative, Interrogative, Imperative and
>   Exclamatory
>
> ... **The best way to distinguish one sentence from the other** is to memorize
>   **what each type of sentence does**, for instance you can say, declarative
>   sentences are the statement sentences, interrogative sentences are the
>   question sentences, imperative sentences are the request and command
>   sentences, or the giving order sentences, and exclamatory sentences
>   are the ones that show a strong feeling or emotion. ...

I agree with the portion I've bolded, but buying into the above passage can be shown to lead to the contradictions we're discussing:

This analysis possibly identifies "You must join with the giants." (or certainly "You must join with the giants!" as a 'command sentence'. The 'what each type of sentence does' analysis thus cuts across the prescriptive syntax-based 'Declarative, Interrogative, Imperative and Exclamatory' analysis - which I believe John Lawler is saying is 'not a model of the English language' - as Cerberus has stated.

Answer (score 0):

Imperatives are almost always fronted with the main verb. Simple as that. Sentences that have the quality of trying to get someone else to do something without this defining feature can be called directives. They can be directive declaratives, directive interrogatives or, indeed, directive exclamatories, come to that. I teach A Level English and examine for one of the main boards in the U.K. and this is how we are instructed to mark.